# How to control number of leading spaces in a GtkWidget?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

How do I set the leading spaces in a GtkWidget? as you can see into below imagem, username/password widgets are a bit away from horizontal line when the window begins

[image]

My code:

```
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *login_label;
  GtkWidget *username_label, *password_label;
  GtkWidget *username_entry, *password_entry;
  GtkWidget *ok_button;
  GtkWidget *hbox0, *hbox1, *hbox2, *hbox3;
  GtkWidget *vbox;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "hello");
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 300);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  login_label    = gtk_label_new("Login");
  username_label = gtk_label_new("Username: ");
  password_label = gtk_label_new("Password: ");
  username_entry = gtk_entry_new();
  password_entry = gtk_entry_new();

  gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(password_entry), FALSE);
  ok_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Enter");

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(ok_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_username), ok_button);

  hbox0 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 5);
  hbox1 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 5);
  hbox2 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 5);
  hbox3 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 5);

  vbox =  gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 10);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox0), login_label, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), username_label, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), username_entry, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox2), password_label, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox2), password_entry, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox3), ok_button, FALSE, FALSE, 5);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox0, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox1, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox2, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox3, FALSE, FALSE, 5);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GtkGrid` inside of a `GtkDialog` is probably more appropriate for the layout you are trying to achieve, however, let me at least help with your code as it is now.

For the packing, I assume you want the `GtkLabel` widgets to be a fixed width, left-aligned. The `GtkEntry` widgets would fill up the rest of the horizontal space.

First, you can control the "alignment" of the text within a `GtkLabel`. Since a `GtkLabel` is a `GtkMisc`, you can use that to align the text. The alignment is a fraction where `0.0` is all the way to the left/top and `1.0` all the way to the right/bottom.

```
username_label = gtk_label_new("Username: ");
password_label = gtk_label_new("Password: ");

/* left align horizontally, center align vertically */
gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(username_label), 0.0, 0.5);
gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(password_label), 0.0, 0.5);
```

Assuming you are using GTK+ 3, you probably should ditch the deprecated `gtk_hbox_new()` and `gtk_vbox_new()` functions in favor of `gtk_box_new()`. I've found there are often unexpected results using those deprecated functions in GTK+ 3.

```
hbox0 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
hbox1 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
hbox2 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
hbox3 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
vbox =  gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
```

Finally, you can change the packing so that the labels do not expand, but the entries do.

```
/* login label fills all horiz space */
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox0), login_label, TRUE, TRUE, 5);

/* labels do NOT expand, but they will fill the space if it's there */
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), username_label, FALSE, TRUE, 5);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox2), password_label, FALSE, TRUE, 5);

/* entries expand and fill all remaining space */
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), username_entry, TRUE, TRUE, 5);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox2), password_entry, TRUE, TRUE, 5);
```

While it's a little bit out of date, you may want to read [How Packing Effects the Layout](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html#How_Packing_Effects_the_Layout) from my GTK+ tutorial. By playing with packing properties in [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) you can quickly test your layouts before hard-coding them in C.

Also note that as of GTK+ 3, the `"halign"`, `"valign"`, `"hexpand"` and `"vexpand"` are now preferred over the `"expand"` and `"fill"` properties.

**Edit**

Here is a "better" way to do it with a `GtkGrid` which handles the width-for-height geometry of GTK+ 3 a little better and ensures you have both rows and columns.

First, set the `hexpand` property of the entry widgets (as opposed to "packing" them into a box with expand):

```
/* allow entry widgets to expand */
gtk_widget_set_hexpand(username_entry, TRUE);
gtk_widget_set_hexpand(password_entry, TRUE);
```

Next, attach all of the widgets to a grid. You can span the "login" label and the "ok" button across multiple columns:

```
grid = gtk_grid_new();

/* 5 pixels between rows and columns */
gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 5);
gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 5);

/* 5 pixels around entire grid */
gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(grid), 5);

/* "login" spans 2 columns */
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), login_label, 0, 0, 2, 1);

gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), username_label, 0, 1, 1, 1);
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), username_entry, 1, 1, 1, 1);
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), password_label, 0, 2, 1, 1);
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), password_entry, 1, 2, 1, 1);

/* "ok" button spans 2 columns */
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), ok_button, 0, 3, 2, 1);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), grid);
```

The arguments to `gtk_grid_attach` specify the placement, width, and height (in cells, not pixels) for each widget. Check out the [API docs for GtkGrid](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html) for details.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much for explanation and warnings. I did the corrections, but I have still a problem: the `password_label` isn't aligned to `username_label`; there is a small difference. Check out the image: http://i48.tinypic.com/2djbh9t.png and the code http://pastebin.com/acEcWcAR How to fix this?

Comment: And yes, I'm using GTK+ 3. I addded into tags.

Comment: My mistake... you really do need a `GtkGrid` for this so that there can be "columns". Right now, each of the `GtkHBox` widgets' horizontal space is allocated independently of the other boxes. I'll edit my answer with a grid.

Comment: nice :) thank you again. Accepted. Another question: how do I set size of button? `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` is not working.. or can I do it only by putting the button inside a `GtkVBox`?

Comment: Yeah, you always want to let GTK+ size things for you. In the case of your button, ideally you would put the whole thing in a `GtkDialog` which probably will display the OK button as you intend. However, you could also manually pack the button into a `GtkButtonBox` and then set the `GtkButtonBoxStyle` to prevent the button from expanding all the way. Eg. GTK_BUTTON_BOX_CENTER would center the button and it would only be as wide as it needs to be to display it's text (plus margins defined by theme). This is exactly what a `GtkDialog` provides.

Comment: You are really the GTK-GUI. Before to create this thread, I did a lot of googling on GTK, where I find and read some articles from http://www.micahcarrick.com and now you are here answering my question on SO. it's funny. :)

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the type of container that you are using to hold these widgets.

Assuming it's a [GtkVBox](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html) for the outer-most level, with single widgets or more GtkBoxes for the rows, you should look at the arguments to `gtk_box_pack_start()`, especially the `fill` flag.

*UPDATE*: Based on your comment, perhaps you should try using a `GtkGrid` instead of a box, it's easier to get things to line up nicely using a grid.

Comment: I'm using `gtk_box_pack_start()` with fill = FALSE TRUE give me a unorganized control

Comment: Unlike `gtk_box_pack_start()`, not easy do same effect by using `gtk_grid_attach()` and its arguments. I can't get align it rightly, can you give a example? edited: with same effect, but by specifing number of leading spaces, of course.